# Date functions keeps returning null values

Tags: r

I have been trying to format the date and time and instead of changing to datetime, I get nulls instead

These are the codes I used

```
daily_steps <- daily_steps %>%
  rename(Date = ActivityDay) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(date,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
```

I also tried this

```
daily_steps$ActivityDay <- as.Date(daily_steps$ActivityDay, format="%m-%d-%y")
```

but I also got null values.

Please Help
Thank you

Comment: One the first bit of code, there's a typo, should be `Date` instead of `date`. Otherwise, please provide the output of `dput(daily_steps)` in order to make your code reproducible.

Comment: What date format is needed will depend on what your data looks like. If your data looks like `2023-12-07`, then `format="%m-%d-%y"` should work. If your date looks like `12/7/2023 10:24:58 pm` then `format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"` should work. If your data is in a different format, then you will need to adjust the format string accordingly.  So what does your data look like?

Comment: I'd also note that some functions like `lubridate::mdy_hms()` are good at guessing the format as long as you get the components in the right order, or the `anytime` package is pretty good at guessing the format with little to go on. But if you specify a particular format, then if your input isn't in that exact format you will get `NA` results.

Comment: @Phil ActivityDay = c("4/12/2016", "4/13/2016", "4/14/2016", "4/15/2016", 
"4/16/2016", "4/17/2016", "4/18/2016", "4/19/2016", "4/20/2016"

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas I will try it now

Comment: That looks like a `month/day/year` format with no hours, minutes, or seconds, so I would use `lubridate::mdy(ActivityDay)`. Or if you want to specify the format string it looks like `"%m/%d/%Y"`, `%d` for day, `%m` for month, `%Y` for 4-digit year, and `/` as the separator. See `?strptime` for documentation of all the format options.